# transition font-size and margin-top in using css3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a textbox similar to paytm login fields. Below is my code:

```js
$(".textBox input").on("focus", function() {
  $(".placeholder").show();
  $(".placeholder").css({
    "margin-top": "0px",
    "font-size": "11px"
  });
});
```

```css
.textBox {
  height: 50px;
}
.textBox input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.textBox input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00B9F5;
}
.textBox input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
.placeholder {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #00B9F5;
  margin-top: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: font-size 1s linear, margin-top 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textBox">
  <span class="placeholder">Enter your name</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
</div>
```

I want the placeholder to animate as it is happening in the paytm login fields. The transitioning is not happening . Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `-webkit-` prefix for the transition; that will only work on Chrome and Safari. `transition` is well supported now afaik.

```js
$(".textBox input").on("focus", function() {
  $(".placeholder").css({
    opacity: 1,
    "margin-top": "0px",
    "font-size": "11px"
  });
  $(this).attr("placeholder", "");
});
```

```css
.textBox {
  height: 50px;
}
.textBox input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.textBox input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00B9F5;
}
.textBox input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
.placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #00B9F5;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition: .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textBox">
  <span class="placeholder">Enter your name</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
</div>
```

Comment: This is working but only if the text is visible initially. if it is hidden initially and we show it on focus of the text box, then it is not working

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".textBox input").on("focus", function() {
  $(".placeholder").show().animate({
    "margin-top": "0px",
    "font-size": "11px"
  }, 150);
});
```

```css
.textBox {
  height: 50px;
}
.textBox input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.textBox input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00B9F5;
}
.textBox input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: white;
}
.placeholder {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #00B9F5;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="textBox">
  <span class="placeholder">Enter your name</span>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @VadimB !! Working now

Comment: i am not able to make the transition faster after a certain point. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Sure, I've updated code in this answer. Please try again. I use 150 ms as transition period. Set your own value if you need slower/faster. But seems nice :)